# How to remove some element in a list in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl

I would like to remove some element in a list, in below implementation, I wanted to remove 7, 14, 26, 77. And finally print 17, 89, 45, 50. But it seem something wrong(this program run successfully, but print nothing), can anyone help me?

```
// remove from list
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int myints[]= {17,89,7,14,26,77,45,50};
  std::list<int> mylist (myints,myints+8);
  std::list<int>::iterator p = mylist.begin();
  std::list<int>::iterator q = mylist.begin();
  advance(p, 2);
  advance(q, 5);

    for(p; p!=q; p++){
        mylist.remove(*p);
    }

  std::cout << "mylist contains:";
  for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: After you've removed `p` from `mylist`, what do you think `p++` should do?

Comment: this program run successfully, but print nothing

Comment: How many elements do you initially add to `mylist`?

Comment: an typo mistake, it should be myints+8

Comment: `std::list::remove` seems like a bizarre choice, do you know what it does?

Comment: Drop the loop with `remove`. Replace it with this line: `mylist.erase(p, q);`

Comment: mylist.remove(*p) invalidates p iterator. After that referring to p results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::list::remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/) 
removes all elements with the specified **value** from the list.

[`std::list::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) removes an element with the specified **position** from the list.

What you're trying to use is the range overload of erase: `erase (iterator first, 
iterator last)`

```cpp
mylist.erase(p, q);
```

will do what you expected

Comment: Thanks. Another question, if I change p and q to const_iterator, how can I use erase?

Comment: @kdhug886 just do the same. See the linked reference: "Member types iterator and const_iterator are bidirectional iterator types that point to elements." (C++11)

Comment: but when I change  these two lines:
 list<int>::const_iterator p = mylist.begin();
 list<int>::const_iterator q = mylist.begin();

an error appear: 
error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::list<int>::erase(std::__cxx11::list<int>::const_iterator&, std::__cxx11::list<int>::const_iterator&)'
     mylist.erase(p, q);

Comment: well, [it works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ac3437c5d2e724) you have to have c++11 compiler at least